# ReferenceError: SPClientTemplates is not defined

Tags: 2013, people-picker, client-object-model, rest

I am trying to use the client-side People Picker and I can't get it to initialize the people picker due to `SPClientTemplates` not being defined. I am following [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593(v=office.15).aspx) line by line but cannot figure out why it isn't defined.

**Script Prereqs**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitecol.com/_layouts/15/clientforms.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitecol.com/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sitecoll.com/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
```

**Code**

```
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
 try{
    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);

   /* I have also tried using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded to see if it is a timing 
      issue and that doesn't seem to be the case.

       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
             this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
       }, 'clientpeoplepicker.js');
   */
 }
 catch (err) {
    console.log('initializePeoplePicker: ' + err.toLocaleString());
 }    
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @hu da the location is the same as clientforms.js "_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. I was not including a the `clienttemplates.js`... Eventhough it was appearing in Chrome resources.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clienttemplates.js"></script>
```

Location of `clienttemplates.js`:

```
--I'm sure this version is subject to change, but should be able to find new
--path in Chrome from an oob page.
  https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/16.0.6712.1210/clienttemplates.js
```

Comment: ExceptionLimeCat clienttemplates.js is a js library if it where is the link to download
Thanks

Comment: I'd also like to know where to find clienttemplates.js file

Comment: @MichalHainc js file location added.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat yes found, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included all these files

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>  
<script src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>  
<script src="_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
```

I had the same issue and once I added all these file, it worked fine